# Add value of two variables into one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, concatenation

Quick javascript question.  I am trying to create a variable that equals the width of two other variables.  I have:

```
            var mainNavWidth = mainNav.width();
            var remainWidth = $('#header .main-wrap').css("margin-right");
            var subNavWidth = remainWidth + mainNavWidth;
```

The first two variables are spitting out numbers as I would like them two, but the third variable is not working.  I know this has to be an easy fix, I'm just not sure how.  Any help is much appreciated

Comment: And what does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `parseInt()` the margin one, since margin will/can return string like `"0px"/"10px"` etc so you need to convert it into integar before adding

```
var remainWidth = parseInt($('#header .main-wrap').css("margin-right"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`var remainWidth = $('#header .main-wrap').css("margin-right");`

The .css() method returns a string, for instance "20px" or "100%" or "inherit", so it's not always a number !

`var remainWidthAsInteger = parseInt($('#header .main-wrap').css("margin-right"));
var remainWidth = (remainWidthAsInteger == NaN) ? 0 : remainWidthAsInteger;`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery returns the value with 'px' so :

```
var mainNavWidth = mainNav.width();
var remainWidth = $('#header .main-wrap').css("margin-right");
var subNavWidth = parseInt(remainWidth) + parseInt(mainNavWidth);
```

Comment: width doesnt needs to be in parseInt(), as it is already in integar